# Why this value is changing?

Tags: c

I've just started learning C language. so I was doing some exercises and I had a problem with this one.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    double l[2];
    double s, v, d;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3 && l[i] >= 0; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &l[i]);
        if ( l[i] < 0)
        {
            printf("Please type a positive value\n");
            l[i+1]=-1;
        }
    }
    if (l[0] >= 0 && l[1] >= 0 && l[2] >= 0)
    {
        s = 2 * ((l[0] * l[1]) + (l[0] * l[2]) + (l[1] * l[2]));
        v = l[0] * l[1] * l[2];
        d = sqrt(pow(l[0],2)+pow(l[1],2)+pow(l[2],2));
        printf("%.2f\n%.2f\n%.2f\n", s, v, d);
    }
}
```

The output gives right value for "s", but it changes l[2] value after "s" is stored, consequently it gives me wrong values for "v" and "d". I dont understand why l[2] is changing, anyone could help?

Comment: your l array is only 2 in size, so calling l[2] is an array out of bounds error, as arrays are referenced from 0 to size-1

Comment: You have **two** undefined behaviors in the header of the very first for loop (`l[i]` is both out of bounds for i = 2 and reads the uninitialized member of `l`). Don't expect your program to do **anything** meaningful.

Comment: Above and beyond any errors, this is really hard to read. Use intelligible variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition

```
double l[2];
```

defines an array with space for 2 values of type `double`.

The array elements can be accessed with `l[0]` and `l[1]`. Accessing `l[2]` (as you are doing) is an error.

Comment: Thank you and everyone who answer!

Comment: Why isn't the compiler catching this?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen because 1) C allows you to shoot yourself in the foot and 2) `l[2]` is the same as `*(&l[0] + 2)` and the compiler doesn't check if the addition generates an address outside the initial object.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen A good compiler really should catch this (mine did) -- after all, the array is static and it's being indexed via the int literal `2` which is clearly out of bounds. Yes, C lets you shoot yourself in the foot, but this has no bearing on the compiler's ability to issue warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing `l[2]` results in undefined behavior.  Arrays in C are 0-indexed and `l` only contains two elements, i.e., `l[0]` and `l[1]`.  Your loop should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2 && l[i] >= 0; i++)
```

And you should probably just store the size in a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Your program invokes undefined behavior;
1. You are reading/writing to an unallocated memory location.
2. In your `for` loop you are reading uninitialized variable.

Comment: and reads from. And reads from uninitialized memory. All that in the very first loop. I wonder if people actually RTFM nowadays...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the answer for why the value is changing would be that since the memory location at l[2] is not allocated to your program, it is probably allocated to some other program, which is changing it's value. Even when you are reading some stuff into it, some other program is trying to change it again. 
Again, there is still a fair chance that the code would work fine if you are not running many processes. This is because, if the memory block containing l[2] is empty, it doesn't change over time.
However, accessing variables out of your scope is a bad practice and would give you errors in other compilers.

Answer (score 0):

error is in accessing l[2]

if (l[0] >= 0 && l[1] >= 0 && **l[2]** >= 0)